# Repeat insert query with a different date given by a frequency

Tags: php, date

I'm building a system where an user can register activities. However the activities registered can repeat over the course of the year.

In order to prevent having the need that the user has to fill in the form to create an activity multiple times for each different date, I had the idea to add a textbox and a dropdown to the form to allow the user to fill in a frequency. The user can fill in a number in the textbox (for example "2") and select a value from the dropdown (for example "week"). So from that selection the activity has to be added to the database for the next 2 weeks on the same day.

However I have no idea how to let PHP adjust the date and add exactly 7 days to the selected date and repeat the same insert query with the new date, for every week/month/year selected from the given frequency.

EDIT 1:

I've tried this so far:

```
while ($i> 0)
                    {                       
                        $query2 = $this->db->connection->prepare("INSERT INTO activity(Act_Startdate) values (?)");
                        $query2->bind_param("s", $Startdate);
                        $query2->execute();

                        $Dates = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($Startdate . '+ 1 days'));
                        $Startdate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($Dates));

                        $i--;
                    }
```

The first date insertion works, but the second one results `0000-00-00`.

Comment: The best place to start http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php. What you have tried so far ?

Comment: @AlankarMore Sorry for the slow reaction, didn't had much time to work on this. Thanks for the link, I read it trough and have edited the OP with what I have made with the link. But it doesn't work quite well :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read more about :

[Date Time in PHP.](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

[Date Interval in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

```
  $numberPostedByUser = $_POST['your_input_name_in_form'];
    $currentDate = new \DateTime(); // Getting current date 
    $iterator = 1;
    while ($iterator <= $numberPostedByUser) {
        $currentDate->add(new \DateInterval('P1D')); // Adding interval of one day in current date
        $startDate = $currentDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // converting that day in convenient format we required

        $query2 = $this->db->connection->prepare("INSERT INTO activity(Act_Startdate) values (?)");
        $query2->bind_param("s", $startDate);
        $query2->execute();

        $iterator++; // increasing iterator for next loop
    }
```

Hope may this code will help you.

Comment: Actually, even though this worked, the answer was more simple then this and now I feel stupid for creating this topic in the first place :/. `d-m-Y` in the OP should've been `Y-m-d`...